# AR remote assistance WebRTC with opentok.js and three.js

Tags: webrtc, augmented-reality, opentok, tokbox

I'm developing an AR Remote assistance WebRTC in NodeJS, Opentok SDK and Three.js. When I initialize the AR session, the AR experience appears in a fullscreen mode and my video sharing stops which works with opentok session. How can I create a AR scene with my opentok video sharing for my video sharing doesn't stop?

Thanks.